# Getting rid of imageView tint on UIButton in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have several buttons in my app that utilize images that are pictures.

For the buttons set in Interface Builder, I set the image in attributes inspector. It displays **without** a tint, as I desire. I checked the method used to set the image in interface builder is `UIButton setImage:forState:`

Now, if I try to do set the image of the button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in a `UITableViewController`, there's a tint over the image.

```
// This puts a tint over the button
customCell.myButton.setImage(buttonImage, forState: .Normal)
```

As a workaround, I threw an `UIImageView` behind the button, but when I animate the button the imageView doesn't move, which I find annoying.

I've also tried this:

```
// This results in a blank image on the button
customCell.myButton.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
customCell.myButton.imageView?.image = buttonImage
```

If anyone's got suggestions re: what I'm doing wrong, I welcome your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `imageWithRenderingMode` solves the problem.

> Creates and returns a new image object with the specified rendering mode.
>   A new image object with the specified rendering mode.

I needed to use the `AlwaysOriginal` case:

> Always draw the original image, without treating it as a template.

```
    let buttonImage = UIImage(named: buttonImageName)?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```